# Average Price Issue in Invoice Report Pivot View Odoo

Tags: pivot, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

**Average Price shows in Invoice Report Pivot shows wrong value.
Attaching Image Please check.**
[Screenshot](http://%20https://ibb.co/ncTNvk2)

[image: o]

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Checking the related field price_average has the group_operator property as "avg", that means the query is something like this: "SELECT avg(price_average) FROM account_invoice_report GROUP BY product_id;". Does the result match the values ​​displayed in the view?

Comment: Average is calculated based in total / Qty so the results should be that value right?. But here you can see even for 10 qty * 10 price = 100 total still shows average as 100 !! That point i could not understand. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Are you sure this is how Odoo calculates that average? It is one thing how you expect it to be done and another is how it is actually implemented. I suggested the sql query based on the Odoo source code to understand how Odoo calculates that value. In any case, a quick way to solve this is to implement the field yourself, inheriting the model.

Comment: Yes i tried with another field but still no use

Comment: I am checking in an odoo (13) demo database, and the amounts are correctly shown. Please try to choose total without taxes, just to see what happens, because even in that situation the amount does not match